# How to generate UUID in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, uuid

### How do I generate a UUID in Angular?

I tried the packages https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid-generator-ts and https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/uuid. But I am getting an error, if I install these packages,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create GUID / UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-guid-uuid)

Answer (score 133):

Nothing to do with Angular itself, you can get uuid from one of the popular npm package such as this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

The code looks like this:

```
import * as uuid from 'uuid';

const myId = uuid.v4();
```

---

However, the `uuid` package does **not** define a `uuid` class (type); it just provides utilities for generating and parsing UUIDs as `string`s, and for converting between `string` and byte array representations. So you will not be able to use the type system to ensure that values are valid UUIDs.

Comment: don't forget to add @types/uuid too

Comment: just another import for easier usage: `import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';`

Can be used like this: `const myId = uuid();`

Comment: This library uses CommonJS and causes a warning in Angular: 
example.component.ts depends on 'uuid'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.

Comment: @Sarah exactly, so what is the alternative? :)

Comment: Add types like this: `npm i --save-dev @types/uuid`

Answer (score 17):

With the example of @MrGrigri: If you don't want to compare and keep the random numbers in an array you could do something like this and you don't need a full npm package and have control about how many groups of 4 you want

```
/**
 * generate groups of 4 random characters
 * @example getUniqueId(1) : 607f
 * @example getUniqueId(2) : 95ca-361a
 * @example getUniqueId(4) : 6a22-a5e6-3489-896b
 */
export function getUniqueId(parts: number): string {
  const stringArr = [];
  for(let i = 0; i< parts; i++){
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-bitwise
    const S4 = (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
    stringArr.push(S4);
  }
  return stringArr.join('-');
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you don't need server-side rendering (SSR), you can use the [crypto.randomUUID()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/randomUUID) method that is now supported by all modern browsers.

```js
const id = crypto.randomUUID();
```

Answer (score 8):

I know that this might help some users out there. This is what I have done in the past. I have created an Angular `ID Service` that keeps track of all of the ids that I have generated throughout the project. Each time an id is generated, it is checked against all of the other ids to ensure that it is unique. There are one public property and two public methods.

### Remember

You must generate a new id in the `ngOnInit` method and remove that id in the `ngOnDestroy` method. If you fail to remove the id when the component is destroyed, they the ids array will get very large.

#### Code

`ids: string[]`:
This is a list of all unique ids stored in the service to ensure uniqueness.

`generate(): string`:
This method will generate and return a unique id as a string;
Output: E.g. `bec331aa-1566-1f59-1bf1-0a709be9a710`

`remove(id: string): void`:
This method will remove a given id from the stored ids' array.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class IdService {
  public ids: string[] = [];

  constructor() {}

  public generate(): string {
    let isUnique = false;
    let tempId = '';

    while (!isUnique) {
      tempId = this.generator();
      if (!this.idExists(tempId)) {
        isUnique = true;
        this.ids.push(tempId);
      }
    }

    return tempId;
  }

  public remove(id: string): void {
    const index = this.ids.indexOf(id);
    this.ids.splice(index, 1);
  }

  private generator(): string {
    const isString = `${this.S4()}${this.S4()}-${this.S4()}-${this.S4()}-${this.S4()}-${this.S4()}${this.S4()}${this.S4()}`;

    return isString;
  }

  private idExists(id: string): boolean {
    return this.ids.includes(id);
  }

  private S4(): string {
    return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
  }
}
```