# Angular 6 - Setting a method as the `data-*` attribute for an element

Tags: javascript, angular, html, angular6

My `component.ts` looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-requester',
  template: '<div id="btn-dlg-container"></div></div>',
})
export class RequesterComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  private externalJSHost = 'URI pointing to external JS';

  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document, private elementRef: ElementRef
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit () {
    const s2 = document.createElement('script');
    s2.type = 'text/javascript';
    s2.src = this.externalJSHost; // external script
    s2.id = 'dlshare';
    s2.setAttribute('data-callback', this.callBackMethod); // This is where the problem is
    document.body.appendChild(s2);
 }

  callBackMethod() {
    console.log('SUCCESS !!!');
  }

}
```

The `script` element that I have created needs a `data-callback` attribute which should be a function. This function is executed after the script is executed.

Apparently, **Element.setAttribute**([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)) only takes a *String* as the second argument.

How do I rewrite this so that I can set the `callBackMethod` as the `data-callback` attribute for the `script` element that I have created dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Why not call the method directly once the script has loaded</strike>

Actually, you could define a global function via the window object and pass the name (string) of the function.

```
ngAfterViewInit () {
  window.my_global_callback = (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.callBackMethod();
  };
  const s2 = document.createElement('script');
  s2.type = 'text/javascript';
  s2.src = this.externalJSHost; // external script
  s2.id = 'dlshare';
  s2.setAttribute('data-callback', 'my_global_callback'); 
  document.body.appendChild(s2);
 }
```

Furthermore, should you want to make the name of the global callback dynamic (you may want to if you have multiple instances of the component and you want each to have its own callback) you can generate a unique id ( [How to generate UUID in angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52836247/how-to-generate-uuid-in-angular-6) ) save it in a variable and do:

```
...
window[uniqueGlobalCallbackVarName] = (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.callBackMethod();
};
...
s2.setAttribute('data-callback', uniqueGlobalCallbackVarName);
...
```